# Is there a double meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation, nuances, context

> 図体ばかりでかくなりやがって

In the manga it's translated with some snark, "only your bodies get big" implying their brains don't (they were complaining about working out too hard)

But the anime translated it as "why did you get so big" and Japanese people also understand it as the latter, why is that?

Comment: I'm Japanese and I don't read this sentence as "why did you get so big". There is no "why" in the first place. Are the Japanese people you asked about this sentence also good at English?

Comment: I meant  in the sense of " how did you get so big " there's also a translation of " how dare you get so big"  the native speakers read it this way

Comment: The phrase contains a sort of exclamation, so *how your body alone got so big!*, which should be consistent with your interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

> 図体ばかりでかくなりやがって

The literal translation of this is "Only your body has become large". 図体ばかり is a recurring derogatory phrase that almost certainly implies "But your mind (or personally, skill, etc.) has not grown like your body". Your interpretation seems correct to me, and I don't think there is a hidden meaning unique to the Japanese language.

Usually the listener's body size is not the main concern of the speaker, so "Why did you get so big" sounds off.